# How to loop through an array of Firebase Firestore documents and push values into array

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Firebase Cloud Function in node.JS that reads user data from Firebase Firestore.
I am unable to push the token values into the token array and return all tokens at the end of the function. My code is as follows:

```js
function getTokens(subscribers) {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        const tokenArray = [];
        subscribers.forEach(async (subscriber) => {
            await firestore
                .collection('users')
                .doc(subscriber)
                .get()
                .then((user) => {
                    console.log("Getting user data for user: ", user);
                    const tokens = user.data().tokens;
                    if (tokens) {
                        tokens.forEach((token) => {
                            console.log("Adding token to token array"); // data is available here but does not push into tokenArray
                            tokenArray.push(token);
                        });
                    }
                }).catch((error) => { console.error(error); reject(error); });
        });
        console.log("Token Array -- Final: ", tokenArray);
        resolve(tokenArray);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP code can be corrected and made more concise as follows:

```
async function getTokens(subscribers) {
  const getUser = subscriber => firestore.collection('users').doc(subscriber).get();
  const promises = subscribers.map(getUser);
  const users = await Promise.all(promises);
  return users.map(user => user.data().tokens).flat()
}
```

Some notes:

- decorate the function as `async`, since it includes an await
- don't create any extra promise with `Promise.new()`, Firestore's `get()` returns a promise
- collect `get` promises in an array with `map`, and run them with `Promise.all()`
- mapping the resulting users' `data.tokens` produces an array of arrays.  Flatten it and you're done.
- a `catch` that only throws, is just like having no catch

Comment: I like the .map() with .flat().  Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `async-await` in a `forEach` loop. Try mapping an array of promises and then using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as shown below:

```
function getTokens(subscribers) {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    
    const subscribersDocs = await Promise.all(
      subscribers.map((subscriber) => {
        return firestore.collection("users").doc(subscriber).get();
      })
    );


    const tokenArray = subscribersDocs.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const tokens = curr.data().tokens;
      if (tokens) {
        acc = acc.concat(tokens);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);

    console.log("Token Array -- Final: ", tokenArray);
    resolve(tokenArray);
  });
}
```

Also checkout: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: A couple performance points:  if your ```subscribers``` at the start is not an totally arbitrary list, it would be better to use a query to select them.  Same cost in `reads`, but only one round trip.   Similarly, rather than looping over ```tokens``` and using push(), you should be able to use ```.concat()```

Comment: Thanks @LeadDreamer. I should have mentioned the `in` operator though it's useful only if the array has upto 10 elements.